# CloudFormation Stack Errors with REST API Doesn't Contain Any Methods

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Get the following when deploying a CloudFormation stack:

> The REST API doesn't contain any methods (Service: AmazonApiGateway;
>   Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID:
>   d527f56e-a1e1-11e9-a0a4-af7563b2b15a)

The stack has a single Lambda triggered by an API with a single resource and method:

```
FailureReporting:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
    DependsOn: "MyLambdaFunction"
    Properties:
      Name: "FailureReporting"
      FailOnWarnings: true
  FailureReportingDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    Properties:
      RestApiId:
        Ref: "FailureReporting"
      Description: "Production environment supporting version-1 of the interface."
      StageName: "v1"
  Failures:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource"
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref "FailureReporting"
      ParentId: !GetAtt ["FailureReporting", "RootResourceId"]
      PathPart: "failures"
  FailuresMethodGet:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref "FailureReporting"
      ResourceId: !Ref "Failures"
      HttpMethod: "GET"
      AuthorizationType: "NONE"
      MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: "200"
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
        Type: "AWS_PROXY"
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: "200"
        Credentials: !GetAtt [ 3FailureReportingExecuteAPI, Arn ]
        Uri: !Sub
          - "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations"
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt [ GetFailureKeysByOrderNumber, Arn ]
```

I'm missing where I mucked up.

Comment: Curious any `Events` and `Swagger` for API.

Comment: Nope, there are no event or swagger sections.

Comment: what is 3FailureReportingExecuteAPI?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Put a `DependsOn` the deployment resource:

```
  FailureReportingDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    DependsOn:
      - "FailuresMethodGet"
    Properties:
      Description: "Production environment supporting version-1 of the interface."
      RestApiId: !Ref "FailureReporting"
      StageName: "v1"
```

It's not intuitive. Buried in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-deployment.html) you'll find the following:

> If you create an AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi resource and its methods
>   (using AWS::ApiGateway::Method) in the same template as your
>   deployment, the deployment must depend on the RestApi's methods. To
>   create a dependency, add a DependsOn attribute to the deployment. If
>   you don't, AWS CloudFormation creates the deployment right after it
>   creates the RestApi resource that doesn't contain any methods, and AWS
>   CloudFormation encounters the following error: The REST API doesn't
>   contain any methods.

Comment: I added the dependency like you advised, and the stack deployed like a champ. Thank you!